# Minimal polynomial and Fredholm operator.

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory, minimal-polynomials

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $m_{T}$ be the minimal polynomial of $T \in\mathcal{L}(X)$.
We have $$\sigma_{e}(T)=\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}, \lambda-T \not \in \Phi(X)\}.$$
Where, $\Phi(X)$ is the set of Fredholm operators on $X$.
Do we have this inclusion :
$$\sigma_{e}(T)\subset \{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}: m_{T}(\lambda)=0 \}.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is affirmative, but please see the comments below.  To prove it let us first show the following result.

**Lemma**. Let $A$ be a unital complex algebra and let $a\in A$.  Suppose that $p$ is a polynomial in   $\mathbb C[X]$ such
that $p(a)=0$.  Then the spectrum of $A$, namely
$$
  \sigma (a) = \{\lambda \in \mathbb C: a-\lambda  \text{ is not invertible}\},
  $$
is contained in the set of  roots of $p$.

*Proof*.  Given $\lambda $ in $\sigma (a)$, suppose by contradiction that $p(\lambda )\neq 0$.  Observig that the polynomial $p(\lambda )-p(z)$ vanishes on $\lambda $, we may
write
$$
  p(\lambda )-p(z) = (z-\lambda )q(z),
  $$
for some polynomial $q$.  Substituting $z$ for $a$ we get
$$
  p(\lambda ) = (a-\lambda )q(a),
  $$
and hence also
$$
  1 =  (a-\lambda )\frac{q(a)}{p(\lambda )},
  $$
which implies that $a-\lambda $ is invertible,  contradicting the fact that $\lambda $ is in $\sigma (a)$.  QED

---

The next  question is how to define the minimal polynomial of an operator $T$ acting on an infinite dimensional Banach space.  Mimicking the finite matrix definition I'd say the most natural one is to let $m_T$ be the generator of the ideal formed by all polynomials $p$  in $\mathbb C[X]$ such that $p(T)=0$.

Of course the main trouble is that it is impossible to define the characteristic polynomial in infinite dimensions and hence there is no chance
of even stating the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem.  In other words, more often than not, only the zero  polynomial will vanish
on $T$, in which case $m_T=0$.  If so,  the question of whether or not
$$
  \sigma_{e}(T)\subseteq \{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}: m_{T}(\lambda)=0 \}
  $$
has an uninteresting, trivial affirmative answer.

In the rare instances that some nonzero polynomial vanishes on $T$, meaning that $m_T\neq 0$, then $m_T$ also vanishes on
the image of $T$ under the quotient map
$$
  \pi:\mathcal L(H) \to \mathcal L(H)/  \mathcal K(H),
  $$
where $\mathcal K(H)$ is the ideal of compact operators.

By the lemma we then have that
$$
  \sigma(\pi (T))\subseteq \{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}: m_{T}(\lambda)=0 \}.
  $$
Combining this with the fact that   $\sigma_e(T) =\sigma(\pi (T))$, we have arrived at an affirmative answer.

Comment: Thanks Mr@. Ruy